# xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies for "libssh2prebuild"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, package, libssh2

[Error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLMHd.png)

> Resolved source packages:   Shout: /Users/xxx/xx/Shout
>
> 2024-01-18 13:05:18.256 xcodebuild[79321:5506204] Writing error result
> bundle to
> /var/folders/1p/mnnw00dn62b_1_2jy8xzwqzh0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-18-01_13-05-0018.xcresult
> xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
> Dependencies could not be resolved because no versions of
> 'libssh2prebuild' match the requirement 1.9.0..<2.0.0 and 'shout'
> depends on 'libssh2prebuild' 1.9.0..<2.0.0.

I build this package using Shout while building the application getting the above error.

**Note:** I have a Mac with an M1 chip. I confirmed that the issue also occurs on an Intel chip.

Tried the below steps but was not able to fix this issue.

- in File -> Packages -> **Reset Package Caches**, **Resolve package version** and **update to latest package version**
- In Shout downgraded the version of the package
- Added the package dependencies in the project

Need some support to resolve my iOS mobile application